# Wilting fittonia

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, plant-care

kinda new to the whole gardening scene but I have a wilting fittonia and I’m not sure why, I thought it could be a lack of sunlight because the room that it’s in is in an area in the house where there’s not much sunlight but is well lit, however the other side of the plant seems fine (the right side)
[image: rightside is fine the left is wilting]

Answer (score 1):

They like some bright indirect light, to low light. They also need humidity. These are best for indoor terrarium since the humidity builds up. Bathrooms is where I keep mine. Misting it will help too.

Answer (score 0):

Fittonia does not appreciate direct sunlight - the  best situation is bright daylight, but no sunlight. These plants aren't that easy to grow outside of a terrarium because they like  high humidity - growing clustered with other plants around it will help with that, but otherwise misting regularly will help, as well as making sure its not near any source of heat, such as a radiator. Further information here https://www.thespruce.com/grow-fittonia-houseplants-indoors-1902486